# First login to web site after Azure AD authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an Asp.Net core 3.1 MVC web application. I use EF and Identity
I'm in the process of migrating the authentication process to Azure AD (organizational directory)
I need to find a way to know when the user is login to my site for the first time.

I want to add user-information such as prefered-color, name etc. and to store it in my local DB
My goal is to know when the user logs-in for the first time and redirect him to the profile page for the extra details

Basically, I do it with OnTicketReceived event.
In this event I get the current user after the login process completed, I get the user details from the token and check if the user already in my local DB.
Now I need to redirect it to his profile page if the user record was not found.
I cannot change the redirect URL in OnTicketReceived event, I decided to create a middleware as follows:

1. In OnTicketReceived I check if the user in my local DB and add "NewUser" key to the session
2. Added NewUserMiddleware that runs and checks the session key. If "NewUser" key exits, I generate a new record in my local DB and redirect to the profile page, then I remove the key

It's working but I'm sure that there is an easier way to do it...

- I don't want to create a register button - the site is internal to the organization and I don't need to create an anonymous register page

Some code stuff:
in OnTicketReceived:

```
var db = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<MyDbContext>();
var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
if (user == null)
{
    context.HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("NewUser", 1);
}
```

NewUserMiddleware:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    int? isNewUser = context.Session.GetInt32("NewUser");
    if(isNewUser.HasValue && isNewUser.Value == 1)
    {
        MyDbContext _dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(MyDbContext)) as MyDbContext;
        var identity = context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        string email = identity.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "preferred_username")?.Value;
        string name = identity.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
        User user = new User()
        {
            Email = email,
            UserName = name,
            Color = GenerateColor()
        };
        _dbContext.Users.Add(user);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        context.Session.Remove("NewUser");
        await context.Session.CommitAsync();
        context.Response.Redirect("account/profile", true);
    }            

    await _next(context);
}
```